# Haskell Can anyone explains how the deleteFirstsBy function works with example?

Tags: list, haskell

I was looking for some documentation on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=deleteFirstsBy) and there is a function called [`deleteFirstsBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:deleteFirstsBy) with this signature:

```
deleteFirstsBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

The explanation says:

> *The deleteFirstsBy function takes a predicate and two lists and returns the first list with the first occurrence of each element of the second list removed.*

I don't quite understand what it means. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Have you tried calling the function yourself? For example in GHCi?

Comment: According to the doc (if you follow the link on Google) The deleteFirstsBy function takes a predicate and two lists and returns the first list with the first occurrence of each element of the second list removed. What don't you understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are not completely clear, but after reading the description of `deleteBy`, the meaning should be clearer.

Suppose we have

```
deleteFirstsBy eq [x1,...,xn] [y1,...,ym]
```

then, we take `y1` and try to remove it from the `xs`, using `eq` as our equality predicate. Concretely, we search for some `i` such that `eq y1 xi` is true. If there is none, we do nothing. If there is at least one, we delete the *first* such `xi` we find (the one with minimum `i`).

Then, we delete `y2` from the remaining `xs` list (which might have one element fewer now). And so on for each `yj`.